# How can I build this JSON file in R?

Tags: r, json, nested-lists

Working in R, I am having difficulty building a JSON file that I would use in an API call.

The required format for the JSON file can be seen here:

```
https://developer.trimblemaps.com/restful-apis/routing/route-reports/post-route-reports/
```

The input to the exercise is a dataframe like so:

```
Shipper_Latitude <- c(1,2,3,4)
Shipper_Longitude <- c(1,2,3,4)
r_combine.NewShipperLat <- c(1,2,3,4)
r_combine.NewShipperLon <- c(1,2,3,4)
r4 <- data.frame(Shipper_Latitude,Shipper_Longitude,r_combine.NewShipperLat,r_combine.NewShipperLon)
```

My attempt at building the required JSON file is as follows:

```
# assemble lat and long for starting location:
tempfuna <- function(Lat,Lon) {list(Coords = list(Lat = Lat,Lon = Lon))}
df_jsona <- mapply(FUN = tempfuna,Lat = r4$Shipper_Latitude, Lon = r4$Shipper_Longitude)
df_jsona <- lapply(df_jsona, function(x) {list(Coords = x)})

# assemble lat and long for ending location:
tempfunb <- function(Lat,Lon) {list(Coords = list(Lat = Lat,Lon = Lon))}
df_jsonb <- mapply(FUN = tempfunb,Lat = r4$r_combine.NewShipperLat, Lon = r4$r_combine.NewShipperLon)
df_jsonb <- lapply(df_jsonb, function(x) {list(Coords = x)})

# assemble list of ReportRoutes:
tempfunc <- function(A,B) {list(ReportRoutes = list(Stops = list(A,B)))}
df_jsonc <- mapply(FUN = tempfunc,A = df_jsona, B = df_jsonb)

# create final list:
post_body <- list(ReportRoutes = df_jsonc)
```

I get an error when I use the resulting file in an API call.

I think the problem is that the list items in the ReportRoutes list are incorrectly named.  For example, the first item is named “Coords.ReportRoutes” instead of [[1]]].

How can I rework the above to produce the required JSON file?

Comment: Look into the `jsonlite` package to convert a list to JSON

Comment: It would be much more informative if we know what the error says, since R has soooooo many of them. (I apologize for sounding snarky ... it's like walking into a doctor's office and saying *"something hurts sometimes when I do something"*.)

Comment: The code above does not produce an error in R.  Where I get the error is when I use the resulting file in a POST call to the web service above - and that error seems not to tell me a lot:(see below).

I think the question is how do I update the code that prepares the file I am using in the API call so that the format of the file is exactly the same as what the web service is calling for (see link above).

Comment: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
<- Server: CloudFront
<- Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2020 13:43:40 GMT
<- Content-Type: text/html
<- Content-Length: 1053
<- Connection: keep-alive
<- X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
<- Via: 1.1 2a6d4f11086c689d07041ed2831056ee.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
<- X-Amz-Cf-Pop: YTO50-C3
<- X-Amz-Cf-Id: ZzlnEuWsseoFQ54HKRLCm_PIqVDehAP0b0KpeF6M7hG29Pc2lyDhnA==